# Core Data - Saving Data from Child to Parent Context, Not All Records Inserted

Tags: ios, core-data, concurrency

I am currently running into a Core Data issue in which not all data saved in my child context is saved to its parent when called.  The number of records saved vary, which leads me to believe there is some race condition involved, but after hours of looking at this, I am out of ideas.

**Setup of Child Context**

```
init(managedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext) {
    _parentManagedObjectContext = managedObjectContext

    // initialize managed object context
    privateManagedObjectContext = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: .PrivateQueueConcurrencyType)

    // configure
    privateManagedObjectContext.parentContext = _parentManagedObjectContext

    super.init()
}
```

**Creating Records**

```
private func insertPerson(name:String, hometown:String) {
    let newPerson = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("Person", inManagedObjectContext: privateManagedObjectContext) as! Person
    newPerson.name = name
    newPerson.hometown = hometown
}
```

**Saving Records**

```
private func saveChanges(to moc:NSManagedObjectContext) {
    guard privateManagedObjectContext.hasChanges else { return }

    moc.performBlockAndWait {
        do {
            print("Saving \(moc.insertedObjects.count) objects")
            moc.mergePolicy = NSMergeByPropertyStoreTrumpMergePolicy
            try moc.save()

            if let parentContext = moc.parentContext {
                self.saveChanges(to: parentContext)
            }
        } catch {
            print("[ERROR] Could not save: \((error as NSError).localizedDescription)")
        }
    }
}
```

When I run the code, I get something like the following (let's say 50 records should be inserted):

```
Saving 50 records  // privateManagedObjectContext
Saving 12 records  // _parentManagedObjectContext
```

Again, the number of records inserted by the parent varies, but generally no more than 10-12 records.  I've been unable to find a clear reason for this issue but it feels like a race condition with the objects not being saved to the child before the parent, but that was why I used `performBlockAndWait`.  Any suggestions are MUCH appreciated.

Comment: Is the parent context being saved at all?  The `saveChanges()` call for the parent context happens after the private context has been saved.  So the guard condition will be false (the private context no longer has any changes).

Comment: @pbasdf - thanks for the suggestion.  I tried removing the `guard` statement as a test but that did not change the behavior, still seeing only some records stored in the parent context.  The `guard` was also testing whichever context I wanted to save to.